# Googlebot crawler is indexing and giving value to useless words

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO - Reducing significance of irrelevant kewords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/seo-reducing-significance-of-irrelevant-kewords)

I'm trying to make some SEO changes to my site. One of the problems i'm trying to eliminate is that the google webmaster tools is claiming the most popular words on my site are "700ml" and "USD". (My site is an online store with various currencies, USD being default, and various beverages with 700ml showing up in most of the item names).

What can I do to make googlebot leave these 2 words alone? If I put a dash instead of a space between the price and currency (ie $5.00-USD), will it stop treating USD as a seperate word? How about the 700ml, anything that I can do with that?

It's painful to see my site ranking so low on the words I want, but when i search 700ml and usd it's like on the first page =/

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338396/googlebot-crawler-is-indexing-and-giving-value-to-useless-words)

Comment: I was told it belongs here =/

Comment: When that happens you just need to flag the post to be moved. A moderator will then move it for you.